# I flagged a question twice?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

When I click the "flag" link on [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/244800/qml-and-qfilesystemmodel-interaction-problem), the popup claims I have already flagged it twice:

> - it is a duplicate... This question has been asked before and already has an answer.
>
> you have already raised this type of flag
>
> - it should be closed for another reason... This question does not meet this site's standards and should be closed.
>
> you have already raised this type of flag

I can believe that I flagged it once (as "...another reason..." if I encountered it yesterday), but I'm pretty sure I didn't flag it twice - I cannot imagine that I flagged it as a duplicate of anything.

My flag history agrees and shows only one flag:

> Qml and QfileSystemModel interaction problem
>
> asked yesterday by user136432
>
> off-topic – Andrew Medico 20 hours ago   helpful

Why, then, is the system claiming I flagged it twice?

Comment: Does the same for me. I just flagged it once for movement to SO, and it says the same, duplicate and other.

Answer (score 5):

Its the *type* of flag that has already been raised.  For example, from some Stack Overflow flagging:

Before flagging:

[image]

Flagging:

[image]

After flagging:

[image]

A close vote (or flag) is one of:

- Duplicate
- Another reason

  - Opinion
  - Too broad
  - Off topic

    - All those reasons...

Once you raise a flag on any of these, its a close flag and goes into the close review queue.  You can't raise it again because its all the same *type* of flag, just with a different message attached.

On the other hand, spam / offensive flags are also the 'same' and go into another type of process.  Low quality flags go into the low quality review queue.  And mod flags go into their special handler.  Each of those are also different types of flags.